# R Shiny remote issue: "Error in Summary.factor: ‘max’ not meaningful for factors" when hosted through R Shiny server; works when hosted locally

Tags: r, shiny

A section of my R Shiny script is giving me a headache. In short, the script receives two data tables: [data_tran](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdRko.png) and [contam_datafile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wko1I.png). data_tran is queried with contam_datafile for any matching IDs under the "Feature.ID" column. A user is then given the option to either *keep* the matching IDs, *remove*
the matching IDs (by turning to zeros), or to do nothing.

```
  data_tran_contam_filt_react = reactive({


  if(input$contam_filter == "Remove"){
    data_tran = data_tran_react()
    contam_datafile = contam_datafile()
    rownames(data_tran) = data_tran$Feature.ID
    # data_tran = data_tran[ ! data_tran$Feature.ID %in% contam_datafile$Feature.ID,]
    data_tran[contam_datafile$Feature.ID,!names(data_tran) %in% c("Consensus.Lineage","Feature.ID","ReprSequence","rowID")] = 0
    rownames(data_tran) = 1:nrow(data_tran)
  }
  if(input$contam_filter == "Analyze"){
    data_tran = data_tran_react()
    contam_datafile = contam_datafile()
    data_tran = data_tran[data_tran$Feature.ID %in% contam_datafile$Feature.ID,]
  }
  
  if(input$contam_filter == "No action"){
    data_tran = data_tran_react()
  }
})
```

This **works** when I run the R Shiny app locally within a combined ui/server script. I've tested it with several datasets and it's all good. However, when I transfer it to an Ubuntu LTS-based server, and select the option to "Remove", the app fails and provides the "Error in Summary.factor: ‘max’ not meaningful for factors" within the log files. All other aspects of the R  Shiny script works locally and remotely *except* for the "Remove" function. I'll include the full error log below.

I don't get it. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

```
Warning in Ops.factor(i, 0L) : ‘>=’ not meaningful for factors
Warning: Error in Summary.factor: ‘max’ not meaningful for factors
  86: stop
  85: Summary.factor
  84: [<-.data.frame
  82: <reactive:data_tran_contam_filt_react> [DELETED]
  66: data_tran_contam_filt_react
  65: <reactive:data_long_react> [DELETED]
  49: data_long_react
  45: observe [DELETED]
  44: <observer>
   1: runApp
Warning: Error in Summary.factor: ‘max’ not meaningful for factors
  107: <Anonymous>
  106: stop
  105: data_long_react
  104: exprFunc [DELETED]
  103: widgetFunc
  102: ::
htmlwidgets
shinyRenderWidget
  101: func
   88: renderFunc
   87: renderFunc
   83: renderFunc
   82: output$proc_main_alt
    1: runApp
Warning: Error in Summary.factor: ‘max’ not meaningful for factors
  107: <Anonymous>
  106: stop
  105: data_tran_contam_filt_react
  104: exprFunc [DELETED]
  103: widgetFunc
  102: ::
htmlwidgets
shinyRenderWidget
  101: func
   88: renderFunc
   87: renderFunc
   83: renderFunc
   82: output$proc_new_data
    1: runApp


Execution halted
```

Ignore the "DELETED". It's just a server address and contains some identifying information.

Comment: Different R versions perhaps? Since R 4.0 data.frame [stringsAsFactors](https://blog.r-project.org/2020/02/16/stringsasfactors/) default value changed. Check `R.Version()$version.string` both in the server and your machine.

Comment: Differents libraries / path / environment between Shiny and Shiny Server ?

Comment: @RicVillalba I think this is it. R Shiny is supposed to use the library where the app is located, but I think I misinterpreted that as R Shiny also using base R from that same directory. The server is running 3.x despite having 4.x installed locally in the app directory. I'm going to update the global r-base and see what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Ric Villalba for the suggestion.

This turned out to be a simple R version issue, and likely caused by the change in stringsAsFactors between R 3.x and 4.x. It sent me down a whole 8-hour path of *trying* to update R and encountering package issues, but I have it all sorted out now.

Cheers